# Create beans with values given at runtime and application's factory using getbean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a Java application which is using Spring (v3.2.4 - I currently can't update to v4 or higher).

I have some strings that my application receives during runtime and for each string I need to create an instance of some class where the string is required in order to create that instance but that new instance also needs to use some other Spring beans from the application.

What I did is create a factory that receives these input strings on each method invocation and then create the relevant instances.

now, my question is: how should this factory create theses new instances?

I thought of 2 different ways to do this (i'll be more than happy to hear of another way if one exists):

1. The factory creates the instances by itself - if I choose this option then the factory also needs to get its hands on a quite a few different beans from the application (these beans are collaborating with the new instance i'm trying to create and can be injected to the factory) - this requires quite a few injections to the factory and also some setup
2. the factory asks Spring for new instances on each method invocation - the factory can get a beanfactory instance and then create the required beans using the getbean method (this will happen on each method invocation) and then set the input string on the received instance

The 1st option seems to be more decoupled from Spring but requires more code and setup while the 2nd option seems to require much less code but it's completely coupled to Spring

Which of these is a better option to use? is there another way that I didn't think of instead? (I obviously googled it but haven't found something enlightening)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2 seems easier , but the instance(s) returned from your factory are not spring container managed. I would not go with either of them. It would be good to register your instance with spring container.Like this

```
public void registerMyInstancewithSpringContainer() throws Exception {
        MutablePropertyValues propertyValues = getExecutorBeanPropertyValue();//dynamic property fetch.
        GenericBeanDefinition executorBeanDef = getBeanDefinition(propertyValues); // create bean definition.
        beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("myinstance", executorBeanDef);//register with registry

    }

public GenericBeanDefinition getExecutorBeanDefinition(MutablePropertyValues propertyValues) {
        GenericBeanDefinition executorBeanDef = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        executorBeanDef.setPropertyValues(propertyValues);
        executorBeanDef.setBeanClass(getExecutorClass());
        executorBeanDef.setAutowireCandidate(true);
        return executorBeanDef;
    }
```

Comment: Amit, thanks for the response, what do I get from registering these beans? where does the code you wrote reside? is it in the factory that I suggested? and where do I add the input string that should be used in order to create these instances?